# Phonegap Build or Testflight

Tags: android, ios, testflight, phonegap-build

Requirements:

Deploy Sencha Touch 2.1.1 application bundled with Cordova 2.6 to group of test users consisting of Android and iOS mix.

iOS needs to be distributed with Ad Hoc distribution licensing option.

Have looked into Testflight and Phonegap Build as options. While It looks like Testflight will handle my needs for distribution of my app to my test users, it looks like Phonegap Build might also, but I am in the dark on this, since it is not clear from their web site.

Any thoughts? Experiences with these services? I know iOS is the tougher of the 2-platforms to get configured for deployment, especially for multiple users.

Comment: As a followup to this question, we decided to use TestFlight. So far it has worked quite well.